# JQuery - Clone Tabs but keep original hidden?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am cloning a JQuery UI Dialog with Nested UI Tabs.  I need to hide the original Tabs elements (or have them offscreen), but still be able to clone and show the cloned Tabs.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="dialog">
                <div class='tabs'>
                    <ul>
                        <li data-type="presentations"><a href="#presentations">Presentations</a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-type="outcomes"><a href="#outcomes">Learning Outcomes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-type="conditions"><a href="#conditions">Core Conditions</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="presentations"></div>
                    <div id="outcomes"></div>
                    <div id="conditions"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
      <button id='button'>Create Tabs</button>
```

and

```
//$('.tabs').hide();

$('#button').click(function() {
  $('.dialog').clone().appendTo('body').removeClass( 'dialog' ).tabs();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewszqx10/1/)

If this is not feasible, then I guess a fall back would be to create the tabs dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: none` to the class `dialog` in your .css file:

```
.dialog {
    display: none;
}
```